# Python - как превратить столбцы pandas в list при помощи for?

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет. Есть таблица в pandas, все столбцы которой нужно перевести в list. Но так как количество столбцов может быть разным, то создавать каждый раз строку с list (как в моем варианте) неудобно. Есть ли возможность сделать это  через for?

```
import pandas as pd

xx = pd.DataFrame({'fig_2': [15, 65, 24], 'fig_1': [1, 0.606, 0.107]})
ddd=list(xx['fig_2'])

print(ddd)
```

Comment: `xx.columns` - список имен колонок. По нему и пишите цикл.: `for n in xx.columns: ddd=list[n]`

Answer (score 2):

можете получить список списков (ndarray):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'fig_2': [15, 65, 24], 'fig_1': [1, 0.606, 0.107]})
res = df.values.T
print(res)
```

```
 [[15.    65.    24.   ]
 [ 1.     0.606  0.107]]
```